# How can I get this input element to fill all remaining space on the page without being pushed to the next line?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to recreate Zork, and so I have a large chunk of text that always ends with ">" on a new line, to mark where the input area is, as seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEiDg.png

The issue is that I'd like that input area to take up the remaining space on the page. Everything I have tried so far either pushes it to the next line, or works but is pretty janky in terms of implementation. To get it to work I had to break the text into two sections, the majority of the text, and the indicator. This can be seen here:

```html
    <div id="game-text">
        West of House<br/>
        You are standing in an open field west of a white house,
        with a boarded front door.<br/>
        There is a small mailbox here.<br/>
        <br/>
    </div>

    <span id="indicator">
        >
    </span>

    <span id="input-span"><input id="user-input"/></span>
```

```css
#indicator{
    display: table-cell;
}
#input-span {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
#user-input{
    width: 100%;
}
```

This works, but ideally i'd like to remove the indicator span entirely and have the '>' symbol placed within the game-text div itself, which I imagine from my experimenting will require me to switch the div to a span anyways. Any help to smooth this out would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is what i'd like the html to end up looking like, if possible:

```html
    <span id="game-text">
        Big wall of text<br/>
        <br/>
        >
    </span>

    <span id="input-span"><input id="user-input"/></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use another span around the > to get the desired look. You can use `display:flex;` and add `flex-grow:1;` to the input to make it fill the row.

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

.user-input-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
}

#user-input {
  margin-left: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="game-text">
  West of House<br/> You are standing in an open field west of a white house, with a boarded front door.<br/> There is a small mailbox here.<br/>
  <br/>
</div>

<div class="user-input-container">><input id="user-input" /></div>
```

Comment: This looks like an elogant solution, so thank you for that. However I may have been unclear with how i'd like the final code to be structured. In your case you've still positioned the '>' within a container with the user input field. I'd however like the symbol to be raw text housed within the game-text div. Hopefully that's not a difficult change.

Comment: I read that and understood that, but that isn't how it is positioned in the image you provided. Div's are block level elements that split the code onto new lines, so I split it the way I thought it would take the least amount of markup. Can you explain why you want to put that > in the game-text div? That might help me or someone else understand your goals. If we did that and put the input in that div too, that would be alright. If the > is in the text div, and the input is in a following div, it would be `pretty janky in terms of implementation` like some of the other styles you've tried.

Comment: I just think that putting all the text together would look cleaner, and make appending text a lot easier without having to explicitly add an extra > every time something is entered. I eventually resorted to just hardcoding the width as a pixel value so it fits nicely, although this isn't necessarily a proper solution.

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't modify the > or input, you would just update the game-text area and clear the input so you can accept more input. Having the > in the separate div should actually make it easier to code; it seems like your way means you have to keep caring about the >. Regardless - I'm happy that you have it working!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flex properties:

**HTML**

```
<div class="flexContainer">
    <span> 
        > 
    </span>
    <input id="user-input"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flexContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    input{
        width: 100%
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to use the table-layout, then you need a parent acting like a table and only set the first span as a cell, ***This should not be your answer*** :

```css
p[id] {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#indicator {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 0;/* first funny thing about table-layout */
}

#input-span {
  display: block;/* nop , i'll be a block, not a cell, so i use the whole space left !! */
}

#user-input {
  width: 100%;/* let's use the width of my parent */
}
```

```html
<p id>                           <!-- i'll be a table or tbody, tr -->
  <span id="indicator"> > </span><!-- i'll be a cell -->
  <span id="input-span">         <!-- i'll be a block -->
    <input id="user-input"/>     <!-- i'll be resized to 100% width -->
  </span>
</p>
```

But today, flex or grid are better option and much more easy to understand and set in action ;) that's what i'd go for. In any case, you'll need to wrap those elements together.